# Azure CLI running .sh script on windows

Tags: azure-cli

Is it posible to run .sh files from `Azure-CLI` in windows command line.

Following is the `cosmosDB` collection creation script that I'm trying to run on local `Azure-CLI`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set variables for the new account, database, and collection
resourceGroupName='testgropu'
location='testlocation'
accountName='testaccount'
databaseName='testDB'
prefix='prefix.'
tenantName='testTenant'

collectionTest='.test'

originalThroughput=400 
newThroughput=500

az cosmosdb collection create \
    --resource-group $resourceGroupName \
    --collection-name "$prefix$tenantName$collectionTest" \
    --name $accountName \
    --db-name $databaseName \
    --partition-key-path "/'\$v'/testId/'\$v'"
```

Is it posible to run these commands as a script from Azure-CLI like in linux `. test.sh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you cannot run the bash script like in Linux `. test.sh`. But you can run the bash script in the command prompt if you install the WSL in your windows like this:

```
bash test.sh
```

Additional, if you do not install the WSL in your windows, then the `bash` is not recognized as an internal or external command. And you also cannot use the `bash` command in the PowerShell.

**Note**: you should take care of when you create the bash script in your windows, there are different about the chars between Windows and Linux. You can use the tools that support multiple languages, for example, the notepad++.